# Second field in /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, password, shadow

If the second field of the `/etc/shadow` file is set to `!!`, does it mean that the account is disabled? Or does it mean that the account is active with no password assigned?

Answer (score 8):

If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance `!` or `*`, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means e.g .key based login).

`crypt()` is the password encryption function.  It is based on the Data Encryption Standard algorithm with variations intended (among other things) to discourage use of hardware implementations of a key search key is a user's typed password. Salt is a two-character string chosen from the set `[a–zA–Z0–9./]`. Following are some status exception values.

- "NP" or "!" or null - No password, the account is locked, no user can log in.
- "LK" or "*" - the account is Locked, user will be unable to log-in
- "!!" - is a Red Hat convention that means a password has never been set
  before. It is treated the same as "!"

Sources: `man shadow` and `man 3 crypt`, [Shadow File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_password) from Wikipedia and [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Introduction_to_System_Administration/s1-acctsgrps-rhlspec.html).

Comment: This information contradicts what actually says in (my version of) `man shadow`. There it says that * or ! would mean a locked account..And for that matter that field can contain anything you want that is not a valid resolut of `crypt` function. So you can actually write in plain english ":this account is disabled:". If the 2nd field is empty, ie :: that means there's no password/any password will work.

Answer (score 4):

That would mean an account disabled for password based login. An account with an empty password will have an empty field.

Comment: No, an account with `!!` in the password field of `/etc/shadow` can still log in. Just not with a password. A common case is an account that only allows ssh logins with a key pair.

Comment: Good catch @Gilles , updated answer.